# Symfony event listener not firing

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling

I'm scratching my head over this one, so maybe someone can help me out. I've done this before without any issue, but I'm new to Symfony so it's likely I'm missing something this time around.

I'm trying to load an event listener to fire some code whenever I save an entity.

In my app/config/config.yml I put this.

```
services:
    fu_bar.listener:
        class: Fu\BarBundle\EventListener\AuthCheckListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, connection: default }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, connection: default }
```

In my Fu\BarBundle\EventListener\AuthCheckListener I'm just doing this so I can see I'm hitting these methods, which I'm not.

```
<?php
namespace Fu\BarBundle\EventListener;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class AuthCheckListener {
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        file_put_contents('/tmp/yyy', 'ffdf');
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        file_put_contents('/tmp/xxx', 'fff');
        //$this->syncAuth($args);
    }    
}
```

When I save an entity, I'm expecting to see some file(s) in /tmp, but I'm not. It doesn't appear that the event listener is being registered.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doctrine:event_listener` should be `doctrine.event_listener`

- use *dot notation* for services and parameters
- use *colon notation* for controllers,views, and these kind of "objects"

Comment: I changed it to dot from colon, but it is now working.

Comment: I spoke too soon, after clearing out my cache, the dot-notation did it. I marked your answer as correct. Thanks. That little error wasted a bunch of my time. Grr new framework. It would be nice if Symfony had a way to tell us when there's an invalid event specified.

Comment: @gnarly: it would be great but this is only a convention so you can make your own tag and call it `foo:bar:tag` and use that way and make all things work like a charm ... So it will not be possible to do such kind of controls :)